# Checkboxes inside listbox alignment WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox, listbox

I added checkboxes to my listbox but they are not aligned as I want to. Here is my `XAML`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path= Reminders}" Grid.Row="2" Height="250" Width="250" Name="reminderListBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Reminder, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >                                   
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                                               
            <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="/WPFPanErpLite;component/Images/bullet.png" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Text}" FontSize="15"  Foreground="#003366" />
            <CheckBox Grid.Column="2" Name="IsDone" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />                                                
         </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Checkboxes are shown but problem is that they "stick" to content of my textblock. I want to move my checkboxes to right edge of my listbox, and want them to be aligned like when you add checkbox column to datagrid or listview. How to manage this?

**UPDATE:**

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path= Reminders}" Grid.Row="2" Height="250" Width="250" Name="reminderListBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Reminder, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
                                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                                </Style>
                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <DockPanel>
                                            <Image DockPanel.Dock="Left" Source="/WPFPanErpLite;component/Images/bullet.png" />                                                
                                            <CheckBox DockPanel.Dock="Right"  Name="IsDone" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" FontSize="15"  Foreground="#003366" />
                                        </DockPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your layout is wrong. a `StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"` will NOT stretch horizontally to it's container.

Change that by a `DockPanel`:

```
 <DockPanel>                                               
     <Image DockPanel.Dock="Left" Source="/WPFPanErpLite;component/Images/bullet.png" />
     <CheckBox DockPanel.Dock="Right" />                                                
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" FontSize="15"  Foreground="#003366" />
 </DockPanel>
```

Also make sure your `ListBoxItem`s are stretched:

**Edit:**

I meant that you set this style as the `ListBox.ItemContainerStyle`, like so:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
       <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
           <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
           <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
       </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

    <!-- ... -->
</ListBox>
```

Otherwise, the ListBox will "think" that you're trying to set the `Style` as an `Item` inside it.

Comment: I changed StackPanel by a DockPanel but I still have the same problem.

Comment: @stojdza make sure your ListBoxItems are stretched. Also make sure that you're setting the DockPanel.Dock property correctly, and that the `TextBox` is the last child. Otherwise post your current XAML.

Comment: Sorry didn't saw your update about stretch. I changed my code but now, content of my textblock is not visible, there is only image and checkbox, and my checkbox is still not moved to the right. I updated my question with new xaml.

Comment: Good Lord I totally missed that part?! Thank you for your answer, it's exactly what I wanted to manage! Never used DocPanel before.

Answer (score -1):

Set Margin

```
<CheckBox Grid.Column="2" Name="IsDone" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
```

Or

```
<Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="/WPFPanErpLite;component/Images/bullet.png" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding OwnerId}" FontSize="15"  Foreground="#003366" />
                    <CheckBox Grid.Column="2" Name="IsDone" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="Red"/>
                </Grid>
```

Comment: -1 That does not meet the OP's requirement "`I want to move my checkboxes to right edge of my listbox`". See my answer.

Comment: I think that the issue is that CheckBox doesnt have space to Align so OP Explicitly need to give it some Width/Margin to Align to Right or Left.

Comment: no of course not. hardcoding sizes in WPF is almost always considered bad practice and unnecessary.